# Migration from manifest v2 to V3 content script not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Describe the bug
migrating a chrome extension from manifest v2 to v3, content script static not working, dynamic also not working,
"chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts( " telling is not a function

To Reproduce
scenario1
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
1.  create an extension with V3
2.  mention in manifest one service worker and content script
3.  then upload or refresh the extension
4.  service worker working but not the content script ( static )
```

scenario2
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

```
1.  create an extension with V3
2.  mention in manifest one service worker
3.  in service worker, the below event either execute or register the script is not working
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: {tabId: tabId},
                or
        chrome.scripting.registerContentScripts(options,function(et){});
4.  then upload or refresh the extension
5.  service worker working but not the content script ( dynamic )
```

Expected behavior

```
in v2 I am able to either static or programmatically injecting the content script in a page where as in v3 is not, so expecting the steps for same in V3 to work
```

Screenshots If applicable, add screenshots to help explain your problem.
Desktop (please complete the following information):
OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome
Version 89.0.4389.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Additional context

```
please help me to resolve or any alternative work around to proceed further for migration
```

Comment: 1) registerContentScripts is not yet implemented. 2) Show the entire call of chrome.scripting.executeScript with all parameters. 3) Show your `permissions` and `host_permissions` in manifest.json.

Comment: 2. 
chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: {tabId: tabId},
                files: ['c1.js']
              });

3.

{
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "alarms"
  ],
 
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}

Comment: Looks fine so the problem may be inside c1.js or elsewhere (maybe you register the listeners inside onInstalled event?). Make sure to click the reload icon for your extension's card in `chrome://extensions` page.

Comment: Hi, i have c1.js, contains only the below statements, alert(1);

if (!document.getElementById('idConfigScript')) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.id = "idConfigScript";
    script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("test_config.js");
    script.allFrames = true;
    (document.head || document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}..

i regiter the listeners not in the oninstalled, it is under

  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

--Suneel

Comment: This is as far as we can go without a demo extension so here's the last guess: open `chrome://extensions` page, click the reload icon on your extension and see if the "errors" button appears.

Comment: even reload everything is done and no error in the console..

not sur how to upload code else i would have been done that

Comment: wOxxOm, can you give me your email id i can send the code what i was trying